# Python ryu package can't import 'ryu.lib.ofproto.inet'

Tags: python, import, module, package

I have successfully installed ryu package for Python using the command `pip install ryu` + corresponding packages. System OpenSuse 12.1, python 2.7.

I can run some basic code:

```
from ryu.lib.packet import ipv4
pkt_ipv4 = ipv4.ipv4(dst='192.0.2.1',
                     src='192.0.2.2')
```

However, when I try to add `inet` module as it's said [here](http://osrg.github.io/ryu-book/en/html/packet_lib.html#) it fails:

```
from ryu.lib.ofproto import inet   #Error here
from ryu.lib.packet import ipv4

pkt_ipv4 = ipv4.ipv4(dst='192.0.2.1',
                     src='192.0.2.2',
                     proto=inet.IPPROTO_UDP)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "packet_ipv4.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ryu.lib.ofproto import inet
ImportError: No module named ofproto
```

What may be the problem?

EDIT:

Got it work like this:

```
from ryu.lib.packet import ipv4

pkt_ipv4 = ipv4.ipv4(dst='192.0.2.1',
                     src='192.0.2.2',
                     proto=ipv4.inet.IPPROTO_UDP)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ryubook a bit outdated. The latest documentation at the http://ryu.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html and in sources. :) As for your example, try:

```
from ryu.ofproto import inet
```

Comment: Thank you, be back with the results tomorrow

Comment: Please, check my edit above, for me it worked like this. Not the most up-to-date documentation for sure